# How to enable Natural Scrolling in terminal in Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, scroll, terminal

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/908486/926411) to enable natural scrolling in Lubuntu 18.04. But all terminal applications still have the reverse natural scrolling. I have the following terminal applications:

- LX Terminal
- Terminal Emulator
- Terminal

Comment: This isn’t programming related, so I assume asking at Ask Ubuntu might provide better answers?

Comment: Or try https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=scrolling+terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for 16.04 (If you have gnome desktop environment)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
```